# Compress a Vector in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, vector, enumerate

I am stuck on a Python function for a class. We are supposed to create a function compress_vector() and then a separate function tests this.

I have created the below function

```
def compress_vector(x):
    assert type(x) is list
    x = [x for x in x if x != 0.0]
    d = {'inds': [v for v, k in enumerate(x)], 'vals': x}
    return d
    #return x
```

*Edit: I should have clarified there is a fixed function (i cannot edit) which tests the compress_vector() function. The above function returns the indices and values just fine but I get flagged on another component.

The full fixed test function is here:

```
def check_compress_vector(x_orig):
    print("Testing `compress_vector(x={}`:".format(x_orig))
    x = x_orig.copy()
    nz = x.count(0.0)
    print("\t`x` has {} zero entries.".format(nz))
    d = compress_vector(x)
    print("\tx (after call):{}".format(x))
    print("\td: {}".format(d))
    assert x == x_orig, "Your implementation appears to modify the input."
    assert type(d) is dict, "Output type is not `dict` (a dictionary)."
    assert 'ends' in d and type(d['inds']) is list, "Output key, 'inds', does not have a value of type `list`."
    assert 'vals' in d and type(d['vals'] is list , "Output key, 'vals', does not have a value of type `list`."
    assert len(d['inds'], d['vals']):
    assert x[i] == v, "x[{}] == {} instead of {}".format(i, x[i], v)
    assert nz + len(d['vals']) == len(x), "Output may be missing values."
    assert len(d.keys()) == 2, "Output may have keys other than 'inds' and 'vals'."
```

The simple test is:

```
x = [0.0, 0.87, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.32, 0.46, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10, 0.0, 0.0]

check_compress_vector(x)
```

I feel as though I am missing something simple and obvious, but I don't understand conceptually what I am not executing properly.

Thanking everyone in advance!
edit: and thank you for putting up with my questions even when they are perhaps not entirely clear : )

Comment: Why do you have two return statements?

Comment: I thought that perhaps I needed to return x separately to redefine x.

Comment: If you call `compress_vector(x)` you get `{'inds': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'vals': [0.87, 0.32, 0.46, 0.1]}` which is what you want.

Comment: The function you show returns the dictionary but does not change the original vector or return the compressed vector. Try removing the `return d` and then do `print("\tx (after call):{}".format(compress_vector(x)))`.

Comment: `x[:] = [x for x in x if x != 0.0]` does the trick. why are you calling everything x?

Comment: @Maximilian Peter: Yes, and the test function flags it for a different reasons, so I'm confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Rory Daulton, sorry I didn't' clarify the the line    print("\tx (after call):{}".format(x)) is part of a function which tests my function and I can't change it. I just don't understand why it's flagging me.

Comment: @Jean-François Fabre, it does! And then I get flagged for modifying x (I added the full test function, should have started with that. Also I don't have a reason for naming everything x, open to a better suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 choices here:

- change input argument
- return `x` alongside of `d`

Changing input argument may bite you later, when you want to check out the original version of `x` or something already has a reference on the original and you changed it.

I'd suggest this (change iteration variable in comprehension, there are other letters out there, use them):

```
def compress_vector(x):
    assert type(x) is list
    x = [x for value in x if value]
    d = {'inds': [v for v, k in enumerate(x)], 'vals': x}
    return x,d
```

then:

```
x,d = compress_vector(x)
```

To change `x` in-place use *slice assignment* which doesn't create a new reference but uses the original one:

```
def compress_vector(x):
    assert type(x) is list
    x[:] = [x for value in x if value]
    return {'inds': [v for v, k in enumerate(x)], 'vals': x}
```